# equivs dummy package version number syntax

Tags: dependencies, version, virtual, apt, dpkg

I try to create a dummy package with `equivs` that provides the `python-oauthlib` package for `apt`. The problem is that most dependency issues are resolved, except for one package that has a version requirement. My question is: how to specify the version number in the `Provides` field?

I did the following:

Create a control file with

```
equivs-control python-oauthlib
```

Edit the control file as follows:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: python-oauthlib-dummy
Version: 0.6.1
Provides: python-oauthlib
Architecture: all
Description: Dummy Python OAuthlib package
```

Build the package:

```
equivs-build python-oauthlib
```

Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-oauthlib-dummy_0.6.1_all.deb
```

Before installing the package, `apt-get` resulted in the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 oneconf-common : Depends: python-oauthlib but it is not installed
 python-oneconf : Depends: python-oauthlib but it is not installed
 python-piston-mini-client : Depends: python-oauthlib but it is not installed
 python-ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python-oauthlib (>= 0.3.5) but it is not installed
```

After installing the package, all dependency errors disappear, except for the last one:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python-oauthlib (>= 0.3.5)
```

This makes sense, because I did not specify the version number for `Provides` in the control file. What is the right syntax to do that? I tried various things, such as `Provides: python-oauthlib-0.6.1`, `Provides: python-oauthlib-0.6-1`, `Provides: python-oauthlib-0.6`, `Provides: python-oauthlib (= 0.6.1)` but nothing worked. Instead, all of the original unmet dependencies returned, with an additional `W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-oauthlib` from `apt`.

I know that the version number of the dummy package itself is not related, I just picked the same number to clarify that it is a dummy that provides this version.

Background: `python-oauthlib-0.6.1` was installed at some point by `apt`. I wanted to install `python-twitter` using `pip`. This requires OAuthlib 1.0.3. Pip could not upgrade oauthlib because it was 'owned by the OS'. Therefore I wanted to uninstall oauthlib in apt, using `apt-get remove python-oauthlib`. This did not work, because a number of packages depend on oauthlib through a chain of other dependencies, including `software-center` and others that I did not want to uninstall. Therefore I removed the package using `dpkg -r --force-depends`. This did allow me to succesfully install `oauthlib` and `python-twitter` in pip, but it rendered `apt` unusable due to the missing dependencies. To solve this I am now trying to install the dummy package.

Comment: As per https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html, the `Provides` field does not carry a version number. That said, I have the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

The `Provides`field may now carry a version number:

```
 Provides: gnome-shell-extensions (= 3.14.2-1)
```

This is supported since dpkg 1.17.11, so since Debian 8 (Jessie).

Answer from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333603/debian-control-file-provides-does-not-satisfy-dependency