# Missing libappindicator3-1 installing Slack

Tags: debian

Here's the output when I try to install Slack.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-4.12.2-amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package slack-desktop.
(Reading database ... 155664 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack slack-desktop-4.12.2-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slack-desktop (4.12.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of slack-desktop:
 slack-desktop depends on libappindicator3-1; however:
  Package libappindicator3-1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package slack-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slack-desktop
```

Then I try to install the dependencies

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  slack-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 148 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I can't figure out why this happens. I've already run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
```

Here's some information that may be useful:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

$ cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

---

Also, I have another laptop running Debian testing with libappindicator3-1 installed:

```
$ apt policy libappindicator3-1
libappindicator3-1:
  Installed: 0.4.92-8
  Candidate: 0.4.92-8
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.92-8 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 38):

I had such issue with new version of Debian 11 (2021-09-07).
Here is what I did to install Slack desktop app on Debian.
I will use `slack-desktop-4.19.2-amd64.deb` file for the example

```
dpkg-deb -x slack-desktop-4.19.2-amd64.deb unpack
dpkg-deb --control slack-desktop-4.19.2-amd64.deb unpack/DEBIAN
```

Open the file `./unpack/DEBIAN/control` and replace
`libappindicator3-1` with
`libayatana-appindicator3-1`

After that do

```
dpkg -b unpack slack.deb
```

Now you should have `slack.deb` file.

The last step is `sudo apt install ./slack.deb`

Or you can use below script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

package="$1"
name="$(basename ${package} .deb)"

dpkg-deb -x "$package" "$name"
dpkg-deb --control "$package" "$name"/DEBIAN
sed -i -- 's/libappindicator3-1/libayatana-appindicator3-1/g' ./"$name"/DEBIAN/control
new="${name}-debian.deb"
dpkg -b "$name" "$new" 
rm -rf "$name"
sudo apt install ./"$new"
```

like this:

`apt-install-libayatana BreakTimer.deb`

Source is here https://github.com/rofrol/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/apt-install-libayatana

Comment: Worked for https://github.com/tom-james-watson/breaktimer-app

Comment: The link to the script was added by @rofrol. I do not have any script. But it easy to do it manually or write your own, it's not too complex.

Comment: The last step, where you have to run `sudo apt install ./slack.deb` didn't work for me (it still throws the unmet dependency error). Doing it like this: `sudo dpkg -i slack.deb` did work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Works really great.

Comment: Did it manually and finished with `sudo apt-get install ./slack.deb`.  No throws/errors and Slack app works fine.

Comment: @mfdebian I ran into the same issue.  But, doing `apt --fix-broken install` followed by `sudo apt install ./slack.deb` worked for me.  On Debian 11 (bullseye) and kernel `5.10.0-14-amd64`

Answer (score 15):

For Debian 11 (Bullseye), you can manually download the Debian 10 (Buster) version of the missing dependencies:

- [Debian -- Package Download Selection -- libappindicator3-1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libappindicator3-1/download)
- [Debian -- Package Download Selection -- libindicator3-7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libindicator3-7/download)

You can then install these together with Slack:

```sh
sudo apt install \
     ./libappindicator3-1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb \
     ./libindicator3-7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
     ./slack-desktop-4.20.0-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 10):

You can include Sid in your **/etc/apt/sources.list** as follows:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main

# SID
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

Update your repos and install **libappindicator3-1**:

```
apt update
apt install libappindicator3-1
```

The next step is to remove Sid from your **/etc/apt/sources.list**:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main

# SID
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

Remember to update your repos to avoid using Sid now on:

Finally install Slack from .deb file you had downloaded:

```
apt install /home/lgallard/Downloads/slack-desktop-4.14.0-amd64.deb
```

Alternatively you can use pinned packages explained in the [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#Force_installation_of_a_package_from_a_repository), for pinning **libappindicator3-1**

Answer (score 9):

It is better to use equivs:

> It's no cruder than going in and munging the dependencies in a package file before you install it, and it has the substantial benefit of persisting the hack over package upgrades on both sides of the spoofed dependency. https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/q7ymc7/convert_deb_to_use_libayatanaappindicator3/hgluc40/

```sh
$ sudo apt install equivs
$ equivs-control libappindicator3-1.equivs
$ $EDITOR libappindicator3-1.equivs
$ cat libappindicator3-1.equivs
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 1.0
Package: libappindicator3-1
Description: dummy libappindicator3-1 package
Depends: libayatana-appindicator3-1
$ equivs-build libappindicator3-1.equivs
$ sudo dpkg -i libappindicator3-1_1.0_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i BreakTimer.deb
```

- https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/q7ymc7/convert_deb_to_use_libayatanaappindicator3/
- https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/HackingDependencies
- [equivs dummy package version number syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796614/equivs-dummy-package-version-number-syntax)
- https://github.com/tom-james-watson/breaktimer-app/releases

Comment: I added `Depends: libayatana-appindicator3-1` and instead of dpkg, used `sudo apt install ./libappindicator3-1_1.0_all.deb`

Comment: Sure, but with equivs it just works for any apps that deb that depends on old lib

Comment: I did use equivs and added `Depends: libayatana-appindicator3-1` to the equivs file.

Comment: I see. So `libappindicator3-1_1.0_all.deb` will not install if there is no `libayatana-appindicator3-1`. So it will only install on newer systems where `libayatana-appindicator3-1` exists.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator3-7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator3-1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libindicator3-7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libappindicator3-1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-4.12.2-amd64.deb
```

Comment: gracias, it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Dpkg-ayatana](https://github.com/mayekukhisa/dpkg-ayatana) to install packages.

I've tested it with [Discord](https://discord.com/download), [Draw.io](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases), [Figma](https://github.com/Figma-Linux/figma-linux/releases), and [Slack](https://slack.com/downloads/linux) on Kali GNU/Linux Rolling.

To install Slack version x.x.x, run:

```sh
sudo dpkg-ayatana -i slack-desktop-x.x.x-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The package `libappindicator3-1` is not in `testing` *but* is [available in Debian `stable` and `sid`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libappindicator3-1)

```
# apt show libappindicator3-1
Package: libappindicator3-1
Version: 0.4.92-7
APT-Sources: http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

Hopefully you can install it from there without breaking anything

Comment: I have debian testing running on a different laptop, with libappindicator3-1 installed via apt.

Comment: @bulkmoustache This answer seems to be OK +1, could you add the output of `apt policy libappindicator3-1` from the other laptop to your question, please.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the output you requested. Thank you.

Comment: This answer was accurate when it was written, but it isn't any longer.  Debian stable no longer include `libappindicator3-1`, nor does sid.

Answer (score 1):

I search for packages on https://debian.pkgs.org/ and download then install. If it requires more packages it would be exhaustive.

https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/libindicator3-7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb.html
https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/libappindicator3-1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Ubuntu package `libappindicator3-1` in Debian is called `libayatana-appindicator3-1`.

The cleanest solution by far in this situation is to create an **alias package** `libappindicator3-1` with `libayatana-appindicator3-1` as its dependency.

For example, using [**equivs**](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/equivs/equivs-build.1.en.html):

```
sudo apt-get install equivs

cat <<EOM >libappindicator3.txt
Package: libappindicator3-1
Version: 1.0
Depends: libayatana-appindicator3-1
Section: misc
Architecture: amd64
Description: fake alias package
EOM

equivs-build libappindicator3.txt

sudo apt-get install ./libappindicator3-1_1.0_amd64.deb
```

Voilà! Now you can install `slack-desktop.deb` as-is normally.

```
sudo apt-get install ./slack-desktop-4.27.156-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69087954/13256105), I have created a slack.deb file which can be installed by normal process.

```bash
sudo dpkg -i slack.deb
```

Link to the slack.deb file: [slack.deb file](https://github.com/LaxmanMaharjan/MyLinux/tree/master/slack)

Answer (score -2):

Enabling snaps on Debian:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
```

and installing Slack:

```
sudo snap install slack --classic
```

worked for me.

Comment: It probably does work, but many people avoid snap packages

Comment: Installs, but none of the hyperlinks open in browsers.

Comment: Upvoted @LucasDolsan's reply, and I would add:  many people also would not want to assist the spread of the snap virus from Ubuntu to Debian.